# Extracting the date of the latest message from an mbox file

Tags: email, unix, grep, mbox

How would I go about extracting the "Date:" header for the latest received message in an mbox file?

Note that it's not simply an issue of grep'ing for the latest occurrence of "^Date:", since it might as well be the date from a quoted reply, not actually the latest message received.

So, probably, some proper parsing would have to be involved.

**grepmail** seems to be good at grinding through mbox'es intelligently, however I can't seem to find a way to achieve this seemingly trivial task with it.

Any input?

Thanks.

E: Okay, I'm officially thick. *ls -l mbox* would probably do. So there.

Still, I'd be very interested in a more creative approach.

Comment: Doesn't this question better suit on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

Since you need something that understands the actual mbox format the canonical mail client `mail` or the customary more capable replacement `mailx` come to mind.

```
mailx  -f /path/to/mbox -H
```

Since new messages are appended that should list your messages in order of reception.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point you could do something like this to find the `From` line at the start of the last mail.

```
tac "$MAIL" | grep -m1 '^From '
```

A line starting with `From` indicates the starting point of a mail within the mbox file. It also contains the time at which it was received, which is usually more reliable than any other timestamp found within the mail headers.

If you specifically want a `Date` header and not the `From` line, you could do something like this:

```
tac "$MAIL" | awk '/^Date: / {print} ; /^From / {exit}' | tail -1
```

This will print the first line starting with `Date:` in the last mail. However if the headers of the last mail have no `Date` header, it could still be matching the contents rather than header, so you would somehow need to ensure the mail actually has a `Date` header.

Answer (score 1):

```
grepmail -hH ^Date: /path/folder | grep ^Date: | tail -1
```

`grepmail -hH ^Date: /path/folder`: `-h` requires the match be in the header, `-H` prints only the headers of matching emails (ie, all of them)...

`| grep ^Date:`: from those headers, extract only the `Date:` lines...

`| tail -1`: and print only the last of those.